# Swift dynamic cast failed on dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

Tags: swift, casting, subclassing, uitableview

my tableViewController get this error msg (**Swift dynamic cast failed**) when I try to cast cell to my custom uitableviewcell subclass after I add a new item in the table.

Here some relevant code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: UITableViewCell

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

        (cell as UITableViewCell).selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
        (cell as UITableViewCell).textLabel!.text = "Some text"

        return (cell as UITableViewCell)

    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {

        cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as SymbolTableViewCell
        let symbol = notClosedSym[indexPath.row]
        (cell as SymbolTableViewCell).loadCell(symbol)

        return (cell as SymbolTableViewCell)
    } else {
        // similar to section 0

        return (cell as UITableViewCell)
    }
}
```

The problem happens after I add a new item to the list and come back to tableView and when it tries to load the last row from section 1. More precisely, it happens in `cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as SymbolTableViewCell`.

Does anyone can guess what could be wrong here besides the fact that the cast has failed?

Comment: Because you said that  var cell: UITableViewCell, but in first section you try to cast it to another class.

Answer (score 0):

Why not declare the cell variable inside the if blocks like...

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as  UITableViewCell
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

        (cell as UITableViewCell).selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
        (cell as UITableViewCell).textLabel!.text = "Some text"

        return (cell as UITableViewCell)

    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as SymbolTableViewCell
        let symbol = notClosedSym[indexPath.row]
        (cell as SymbolTableViewCell).loadCell(symbol)
        return (cell as SymbolTableViewCell)
    } else {
        // similar to section 0
        return (cell as UITableViewCell)
    }
}
```

If you continue to get the same error, double check your UITableViewCell subclass.

Comment: It didn't work BugKrusha.
After crash and restart, it works well with no Cast problem. It shows all rows of tableView correctly.